# How to define the chapter, section, paragraph with a custom numeration and normal-sized, bold embedded headings?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, subsection, numeration

I have to write a seminar paper. It should have the following outline view:

> A. (Big letters)
>
> I. (Roman)
>
> 1. (Arabic)
>
> a) (small letters with ")")
>
> aa) (double small letters with ")")
>
> (1) (arabic letter within brakets)

Further, the headings should be normal-sized and bold.

I tried to achieve this numeration by using the `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\subparagraph` and `\paragraph`. But I had problems regarding the `\chapter`, which is far too big and shows like "Chapter A: Heading", after I set the counter to big letters with `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}` (which I did with the other layers likewise. The problem with the "Chapter" before each heading could be solved with `\chapter*` and insert the right letter manually (but of course that's not the elegant solution).

The

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph){subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\alph\alph){paragraph}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{(\arabic){subparagraph}}
```

of the low levels somehow didn't work as with the upper levels, as the heading is displayed as "heading" only (without the the right respectively any enumeration). Also e.g. the `\subparagraph` is too small.

I tried to redefine the commands, so that all headings show the right numeration and embedded as normal-sized in the text body, and tried a few solutions I found in the internet, but somehow I got to no real, good-working conclusion.

So is there somebody who can tell, how exactly the commands can be redefined, that I achieve normal-sized, bold headings in the style of "A. Heading", "I. Heading", ... (that show up in the `\tableofcontents`) ?

I will be very grateful for any working solution!

Comment: It would help a lot, if you would show, what you've tried by showing a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). Then you could also explain the issues with this code and what should be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not absolutely clear, what you want, i.e., the expected format of the table of contents is unknown. But I think, everything can be achieved using a KOMA-Script class, e.g., `scrreprt`:

```latex
\documentclass[%
  numbers=noenddot,% don't add automatic end dots to number formats
  toc=flat,% use a flat ToC (without indent, depending on the level)
  chapterentrydots,% use dotted lines also for chapter entries in ToC
]{scrreprt}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[%
  style=section,% use section style for all
  indent=0pt,% don't indent
  runin=false,% don't use runin titles
  afterindent=false,% don't indent the first line of the first paragraph following the title
  beforeskip=1\baselineskip,% one empty line before (without glue)
  afterskip=1\baselineskip,% one empty line after (without glue)
  font=\normalsize,
  tocentryformat=,% don't make entries in ToC bold
  tocpagenumberformat=,% same for the page numbers in ToC
%  tocdynindent=true,% for hierachical indent of ToC entries (don't remove class option toc=flat!)
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

%\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{chapter}% optional, of \chapter should start a new page

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection})}
\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\alph{paragraph}\alph{paragraph})}
\renewcommand*{\thesubparagraph}{(\arabic{subparagraph})}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}% number until subparagraph
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subparagraphtocdepth}% show until subparagraph in ToC

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}% use bold but not sans-serif

\usepackage{mwe}% for demonstration in *M*inimal *W*orking *E*xample only

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is a chapter}

\blindtext

\section{This is a section}

\blindtext

\subsection{This is a subsection}

\blindtext

\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection}

\blindtext

\paragraph{This is a paragraph}

\blindtext

\subparagraph{This is a subparagraph}

\blindtext

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image: two pages of the result]

Notes:

- I've used a flat ToC (which needs at least 3 LaTeX runs!), because IMHO indent per level does not make sense, with this kind of numbering. But you can change this (and the indention in the ToC) using additional options. See the documentation of `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` in the KOMA-Script manuals. If you want indent of the ToC levels, you can activate the `tocdynindent=true`, currently commented. However, if you would have problems with further adaptions of the table of contents, please ask a new question.
- I've also made `\chapter` behave similar to `\section` etc., i.e., don't start a new page. If you don't like this, just activate the second `\RedeclareSectionCommand` line currently commented. This would result in:

[image: with real chapters]

You can do similar settings for the standard classes, using a combination of a package like `sectsty`, `titlesec` etc.  with a package like `tocbasic`, `etoc`, `tocloft` etc. IMHO there are already several questions and answers about changing sectioning and table of contents.

Comment: Many thanks! That helps a lot!!

Comment: There would be only two small wishes for improvement: First, there is a dot after the "a)" like "a)." Is it possible to delete this extra dot? And second, in the \tableofcontents (from the design it's perfect) is a lot of space between the numeration and the heading like "1.               Heading". Is it possible to reduce the spacing that it's a normal space? I woult upload the document, but somehow here's no upload opportunity?!

Comment: @oramol There isn't a dot after "a)" in my example. See the screenshot. Maybe you've not used option `numbers=noenddot` in your own code. And as already told: You can configure the entries to the table of contents. If you fail in doing, what you want, please ask another question with a proper MWE and a exact specification.